# Split excel string into two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have column of text in Excel.  Some text may include a special tag:

```
<RL>
```

So you may have this:

```
Some text <RL> some more text
```

Or text without this special tag

```
Some plain text
```

What I would like is a function that can split this text into two separate columns (B & C).  At the point of the tag.  In instances where there is no tag I’d like to copy the entire string into column B
The tag should not be displayed in either col B or col C

Any ideas?

Comment: If you have Excel 2010+, you can use `Power Query` (aka `Get&Transform` in 2016) to split columns on delimiters consisting of more than one character.

Answer (score 2):

Cell B1:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND("<RL>",A1,1)-1),A1)
```

Cell C1

```
=IFERROR(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("<RL>",A1,1)-3),"")
```

Drag down...

Answer (score 1):

In **B1** enter:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("<RL>",A1)),A1,LEFT(A1,FIND("<RL>",A1)-1))
```

and in **C1** enter:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("<RL>",A1)),"",MID(A1,FIND("<RL>",A1)+4,9999))
```

and copy these downward:

[image]

Comment: Beaten me to it :)